# Formpanel expanded by textfieldarea

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I've got this question, I have the following view defined:

```
Ext.define('aBMin.view.TicketView', {
    extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',

    alias : 'widget.ticketview-panel',
    config : {
        layout : {
            type : 'vbox',
            align : 'center',
        },
        items : [{
            xtype : 'fieldset',
            defaults : {                
                labelWidth: '110px',
                labelWrap: true,
            },                  
            name : 'ticketviewfieldset',
            width : '100%',
            items : [{
                xtype : 'hiddenfield',
                name : 'clientemailid',
                label : 'ClientEmailId',
            }, {
                xtype : 'selectfield',
                name : 'clientid',
                label : 'Client',
                store : 'Client',
                displayField : 'clientname',
                valueField : 'clientid'
            }, {
                xtype : 'selectfield',
                name : 'projectid',
                label : 'Project',
                store : 'ProjectSF',
                displayField : 'projectname',
                valueField : 'projectid'
            }, {
                xtype : 'selectfield',
                name : 'ticketstatusid',
                label : 'Ticket status',
                store : 'TicketStatus',
                displayField : 'ticketstatusclient001',
                valueField : 'ticketstatusid'
            }, {
                xtype : 'checkboxfield',
                name : 'warrantysupport_yn',
                label : 'Warranty',
            }, {
                xtype : 'checkboxfield',
                name : 'ourfault_yn',
                label : 'Our fault'
            }, {
                xtype : 'selectfield',
                name : 'supportstaffid',
                label : 'Staff',
                store : 'Staff',
                displayField : 'staffname',
                valueField : 'supportstaffid'
            }, {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                name : 'subject',
                label : 'Subject'
            }, {
                xtype : 'textareafield'
                ,name : 'ticketdesc'
                ,label : 'Description'
                ,tpl : '<pre>{value}</pre>'
                /*,style : {
                    'width' : '100px'
                    ,'overflow' : 'auto'
                }*/
            }, {
                xtype : 'datepickerfield',
                label : 'Eta',
                name : 'eta',
                picker : {
                    slotOrder : ['day', 'month', 'year']
                }
            }, {
                xtype : 'textfield',
                name : 'timeestimate',
                label : 'Estimated time (min.)'
            }]
        }, {
            xtype : 'button'
            ,text : 'Update'
            ,action : 'ticketViewSubmit'
            ,ui : 'confirm'
            ,width : '100%'
            /*width : '10%',
            minWidth : '200px',*/
        }]
    }
    });
```

now... when the view is loaded with content, generaly it displays ok, **EXCEPT...** in the case when to the textareafield is loaded a HTML formatted content (for ex. with a lot of text and it's lines are unbreakable). In such the case my formpanel is being expanded over the device's screen.

Any advices how to deal with such an issue?

Please see attached screenshots to be clear with what I'm trying to deal with.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If somebody in the future will have the similar problem, here's the solution:

```
{
 xtype : 'textareafield'
,name : 'ticketdesc'
,label : 'Description'
,tpl : '<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;">{value}</pre>'
,cls : 'scale-images'
}
```

the

```
<pre style="white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; word-break: break-all;">{value}</pre>
```

template solved the problem (mostly). As an addition, the images can alos 'expand' the view so You can add such

```
.scale-images img {
 max-width : 320px;
 height : auto;
}
```